# c#: how to create a solution-wide ODBC connection?

Tags: c#, odbc

I have a working ODBC connection on one of the projects, but I want to DRY and have the connection class available to the entire solution.

So, I removed the repeating code from every project and created the following class which I then referenced on all of the projects:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public class ConnectWithDb
{
    public OdbcConnection Connection;

    public OdbcConnection Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Driver={" + Constants.DriverODBC + "};Dbq=" + Constants.DbFileName + ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=;";
            OdbcConnection Connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            Connection.Open();

            return Connection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on each project and before the Main() method, I do:

`private ConnectWithDb dbConnection = new ConnectWithDb();`

No errors there. The problem is that when I try to create a command inside any of the methods, I get an error like this:

`OdbcCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();`

dbConnection is underlined and states `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Program.dbConnection'`

I've tried setting some methods and values as static, but that gives a whole bunch of other errors.

**I guess** that ConnectWithDb is not returning an actual connection... is that right? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: you have an `Program.dbConnection` class defined somewhere, so VS thinks, that this `dbConnection.CreateCommand();` is a static method call.

Comment: I cannot find any reference over my project to the connection, outside from the private...new... that I do before the Main method.
Also, if I turn the class static, then I get an error stating that CreateCommand is not defined on the connection class.

Comment: got it! add static defenition to your private field, like this: `private static ConnectWithDb dbConnection = new ConnectWithDb();`

Comment: it's a console app

Comment: have you read my last comment? Your `Program` class is `static`, so, inside your `static void Main()` method, you have no access to field `dbConnection` unless it is static too.

Comment: Sorry, missed it! Sadly that gave errors later about methods like Close not being available. But I was able to move parts of the code into the DB class and keep only the new OdbcConnection part on the Program class :)